# Can I ask for identification of public historical event based on the picture?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Can I ask for identification of public historical event based on the provided picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually get a pretty fair amount of picture identification questions [[1]](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/where-is-the-location-shown-in-this-picture-on-a-modern-day-map)[[2]](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9937/did-the-turret-shown-in-this-picture-belong-to-a-german-battleship)[[3]](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/what-is-this-strange-uniform). I think I saw one questioned on the basis of triviality, and I see [another](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10554/who-is-this-person-on-the-picture) that did get closed because there really wasn't enough info provided. So be sure to provide all the information about the picture you possibly can.

There might actually be enough of them that they deserve their own tag of some kind.